# Fahrenheit and Celsius converter in Rust

Tags: rust, unit-conversion

I made a program that converts between Celsius and Fahrenheit. Is there any way that I could make this code more efficient and cleaner?

```
use std::io;

// C to F: F = C*(9/5) + 32
// F to C: C = (F-32)*(5/9)

/**********Converts between Fahrenheit and Celsius*********/

fn main() -> () {
    println!("Do you want to convert to Celsius or Fahrenheit? Input C or F");
    let mut convert_type = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut convert_type)
        .expect("Failed to conversion type.");

    let t = String::from(convert_type);

    println!("You want to convert to: {}", t);
    println!("What temperature would you like to convert?");
    let mut temp = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut temp)
        .expect("Failed to read temperature.");

    let temp: i32 = match temp.trim().parse() {
        Ok(temp) => temp,
        Err(_e) => {
            -1
        }
    };

    match t.as_str() {
        "C\n" => println!("{}", ftoc(temp)),
        "F\n" => println!("{}", ctof(temp)),
        _ => println!("t = {:?}", t),
}
}

// Celsius to Fahrenheit
fn ctof(c: i32) -> i32 {
    (c * (9 / 5)) + 32

}

//Fahrenheit to Celsius
fn ftoc(f: i32) -> i32 {
    (f-32) * (5 / 9)
}
```

Output:

```
    cargo run
   Compiling ftoc v0.1.0 (/Users/roberthayek/rustprojects/ftoc)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2.64s
     Running `target/debug/ftoc`
Do you want to convert to Celsius or Fahrenheit? Input C or F
F
You want to convert to: F

What temperature would you like to convert?
0
32
```

Comment: Please use `rustfmt` the next time before pasting your code here so it fulfills the rust style guidelines which helps us reading your code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first thing I always do is running `clippy`.

You will catch some things that are not neccessary, e.g.

- `fn main() -> ()` can be reduced to `fn main()`
- `let t = String::from(convert_type);` is simply `let t = convert_type`

The bad things are

- `c * (9 / 5)` which is always `c` because of integer arithmetic. You probably want `f64::from(c) * (9.0 / 5.0)`
- same for `(f - 32) * (5 / 9)` should be `(f64::from(f) - 32.0) * (5.0 / 9.0)) as i32`

You may want to add some [unit-tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-01-writing-tests.html) to your program to verify that `ctof` and `ftoc` actually work.

Answer (score 7):

Hellow got most of the good parts, but, I'd also recommend figuring out how you might want to signal the user so that an invalid input isn't accepted, since -1 is a temperature someone might want to convert.

In this case I would do something like replacing

```
let temp: i32 = match temp.trim().parse() {
    Ok(temp) => temp,
    Err(_e) => {
        -1
    }
};
```

with

```
let temp= match temp.trim().parse() {
    Err(_e) =>{
        panic!("That wasn't valid input! Temperatures can only be integers!");
    }
    Ok(i)=>i
};
```

If I knew this program were to be used solely interactively, then I'd consider adding a loop to give the user another attempt should their input fail.

Comment: Also, if you aren't planning on using the destructured error, you might as well just use just a `_` for it.

Comment: You can write it: `let temp = temp.trim().parse().expect("Your message");`