# Temperature calculator in Rust

Tags: beginner, rust, unit-conversion

Just on a chapter 3 of [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) so not much good in Rust.
so tried to implement a simple temprature calculator as suggest in [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-05-control-flow.html#summary) chapter.
so i would like you guys to point anything you feel

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Enter Temperature as 56f or 98c");

    let mut usr_inpt = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut usr_inpt)
        .expect("can not read user input");

    let usr_inpt = usr_inpt.trim_end().to_lowercase();

    if usr_inpt.ends_with("f") || usr_inpt.ends_with("c") {
        // remove the last indication 56f -> 56 or 56c -> 56
        let _temp: String = usr_inpt.chars().take(usr_inpt.len() - 1).collect();
        let num: u32 = match _temp.parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => 0,
        };

        if usr_inpt.ends_with("f") {
            println!("celcius -> {}", (num - 32) * 5 / 9);
        } else if usr_inpt.ends_with("c") {
            println!("farenheit -> {}", num * 9 / 5 + 32);
        }
    } else {
        println!("invalid input");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I've rolled your question back to its previous state, as it invalidated an already existing review. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: my bad sure will take care of it ...

Comment: Please take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/207481/fahrenheit-and-celsius-converter-in-rust

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> use std::io;
>
> fn main() {
>     println!("Enter Temperature as 56f or 98c");
>
>     let mut usr_inpt = String::new();
>
>     io::stdin()
>         .read_line(&mut usr_inpt)
>         .expect("can not read user input");
> ```

I like that you’re using `expect` here instead of `unwrap`. 
It allows for a much nicer user experience when things go sideways. 
If I was nitpicking, I’d remind you to use proper capitalization and punctuation.

> ```
>     let usr_inpt = usr_inpt.trim_end().to_lowercase();
>
>     if usr_inpt.ends_with("f") || usr_inpt.ends_with("c") {
>         // remove the last indication 56f -> 56 or 56c -> 56
>         let _temp: String = usr_inpt.chars().take(usr_inpt.len() - 1).collect();
> ```

`temp` is rarely a good name. 
If you meant `temperature` instead of `temporary`, it would be good to spell it out.

> ```
>         let num: u32 = match _temp.parse() {
>             Ok(num) => num,
>             Err(_) => 0,
>         };
> ```

Is it really the right thing to return zero in the error case?
I would expect the error case here to be caused by invalid user input (or a bug in your previous parsing logic maybe).
It would probably be best to alert the user to this failure instead of the slightly enigmatic result of `0`.

> ```
>         if usr_inpt.ends_with("f") {
>             println!("celcius -> {}", (num - 32) * 5 / 9);
>         } else if usr_inpt.ends_with("c") {
>             println!("farenheit -> {}", num * 9 / 5 + 32);
>         }
> ```

It smells a little funny that we’re making the same checks again as we did above. If you extracted the parsing logic into a function, you could just call it for each case. I would probably also extract proper `fahrenheit_to_celcius` and `celcius_to_fahrenheit` functions.

> ```
>     } else {
>         println!("invalid input");
>     }
> }
> ```

Error messages should be printed to `stderr`. 
Use the [`eprintln` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.eprintln.html) instead.

———————

All in all it’s pretty good for a first go. 
I would take a look at using some types for `Fahrenheit` and `Celsius` though. Your parse method could return a `Temperature` that contains either a `Celsius` or `Fahrenheit` measurement.

I’ve not run this through the compiler, but hopefully it illustrates the idea.

```
struct Celsius { value: u32 }
impl Celsius {
    fn to_farhenheit(&self) -> Farhenheit {
        Fahrenheit { value: self.value * 9 / 5 + 32 }
    }
}

struct Fahrenheit { value: u32 }
impl Fahrenheit {
    fn to_celsius(&self) -> Celsius {
        Celsius { value: ( self.value  - 32) * 5 / 9 }
    }
}

enum Temperature {
    Fahrenheit(Fahrenheit),
    Celsius(Celsius)
    Err(String)
}

fn parse_input(input: &str) -> Temperature {
    if input.ends_with("f") {
        Fahrenheit { value: parse_num(input) }
    } else if input.ends_with(“c”) {
        Celsius { value: parse_num(input) }
    } else {
        Err(“Input invalid. Must end with ‘c’ or ‘f’.”)
    }
}

fn parse_num(input: &str) -> u32 {
    let temperature: String = usr_inpt.chars().take(usr_inpt.len() - 1).collect();

    match temperature.parse() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => 0,
    };
}
```

Then we tie it all together in main.

```
fn main() {
    println!("Enter Temperature as 56f or 98c");

    let mut usr_inpt = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut usr_inpt)
        .expect("can not read user input");

    let temperature = parse_input(usr_inpt.trim_end().to_lowercase());

    match temperature {
        Temperature::Celsius { celsius } => println!("celcius -> {}", celcius.to_fahrenheit()),
        Temperature::Fahrenheit { fahrenheit } => println!(“fahrenheit -> {}”, fahrenheit.to_celsius()),
        Err(reason) => eprintln!(reason)
    }
}
```

While it’s certainly more code, it raises the level of abstraction in your `main` function quite a bit.

- Greet user
- Get input
- Parse input
- Write out results

This also provides the opportunity (left as an exercise for the reader) to propagate errors from `parse_num` all the way back up to the user, rather than silently returning an invalid result.

Comment: This is helpful, So not completely  but i have updated the code a bit since i am not very comfortable with enums and all in Rust i will follow your advice once i am comfortable with these things..

Comment: No worries @MAK. I kind of figured. That’s why I broke my answer into two parts.